# VsCode is creating a new line when i use template literan inside of getElememdById? How can i fix it?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, prettier

Vscode is creating a new line when I use template literal inside of getElememdById? How can I fix it?

it should be like this:

```
document.getElementById(`current--${activePlayer}`).textContent = currentScore;
```

but

```
    document.getElementById(
      `current--${activePlayer}`
    ).textContent = currentScore;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't affect the code functionality, 
However something that worked here was changing the `max-len` of prettier configs. 
They set default for 80 characteres per line. 
Try using 180 and see if it works.

Checkout more [here](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html) in their doc.

You can change it by setting this option into `.eslintrc.json`

```
.
.
.
"rules": {    
    "max-len": ["error", { "code": 180 }],
     ... // other rules
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vscode is just formating your code for readability. It would not create new line in UI. so no need to worry. by the way you can set formattiong in vsCode but i recommanded default setting.